# Delphi 7 report builder, DBRichtext, how to change style

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, reportbuilder

I (still) use Delphi 7, with Report Builder (Digital Metaphors). I have a DbRichText, I would like to write just the first word in bold. It would be better to use onCalc on the run-time editor instead of coding in Delphi, but I'll acept any kind of solutions and suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution: 
1) I create a memo field in database where I put an rtf text.
   Example:
 `'{\rtf1\ansi \b first\b0 word \par second line}'` 
2) OnCalc function of report builder of a RichView object, I do:

obj.RichView := TableName['rftField'];